# Loading lines with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

In Python 2.7, using Selenium, I want the script to open the 'masters.txt' file. Then, go to Twitter (while logged in beforehand), and post the line like so:

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('tweet')
elem.send_keys(line1 + " #worked")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="timeline"]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/button')
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

then, the same, except:

```
elem.send_keys(line2 + " #worked")
```

then, the same, except:

```
elem.send_keys(line3 + " #worked")
```

etc...

So, load every single line & tweet it + "with another text I've added". How is that possible?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT: Example of 'master.txt' (text file) contents:

```
test
blablabla
awesome
This is an awesome Tweet
something
another line
```

etc...

What I've tried:
f = open("masters.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    elem.send_keys(line + " #worked")

However that doesn't exactly work and messes it up etc... If someone could complete my code and write me what I'm looking for, that would be great! :)

Comment: Please provide an example of the text file contents, and what you have tried for logging into twitter.

Comment: Logging into twitter was not a problem. I coded that using:

driver.get("https://twitter.com")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
elem.send_keys("MyTwitterUsername")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
elem.send_keys("MyTwitterPassword") etc., and it worked just fine. The tweeting part is the issue.